# ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn is cleared after hide the column in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, reset, datagridtemplatecolumn, itemsource

I created simple `DataGridTemplateColumn` containing combobox. I set binding for the `Visibility` of whole column and also for `ItemSource` and `SelectedItem` of `ComboBox` (I need to have different `ItemsSource` for different rows). Everything works fine until I hide the column. After that (and show it again), the `ComboBoxes` are empty, but the getters of `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` binding return good values. When I call setter of `SelectedItem` binding, the previous value is correct and a new value is shown in `ComboBox`. So everything is correct, but why after hide the column the combo-boxes are reset even data in `ViewModel` are also correct and nothing is changed:

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Total" Visibility="{Binding ProxyData.ReportConfigurationVM.ShowTotalRow, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ComboBox Width="70"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TotalsAggregationFunctions}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTotalAggregation, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
           </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My ViewModel:

```
  public enum AggregationFunction
  {
     None,
     Sum,
     Avg
  }

  private AggregationFunction selectedTotalAggregation;
  public AggregationFunction SelectedTotalAggregation
  {
     get { return this.selectedTotalAggregation; }
     set { SetField(ref this.selectedTotalAggregation, value); }  // this calls OnPropertyNotify automatically
  }

  public IEnumerable<AggregationFunction> TotalsAggregationFunctions
  {
     get
     {
        // no matter what I return, nothing works when hide the column...
        return new AggregationFunction[] { AggregationFunction.None, AggregationFunction.Sum, AggregationFunction.Avg, AggregationFunction.Min, AggregationFunction.Max };
     }
  }
```

Screenshot of reseted `ComboBoxes` after hide (and show) column. I know that hide is the proble, because the exclamation marks are shown after hide:

[image: ComboBoxes resete after hide (and show) column]

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the bug described above occurs in cases when ItemsSoure of the combobox is a collection of not-nullable objects (int, enum, etc.). If ItemsSource is a nullable object (string, class), hidnig/showing of columns containing the combobox works fine (as expected).

So you need to use nullable Enum type (Enum?) and then everything woks fine. Workaround is convert Enum to String or wrap the Enum into a class.

```
public enum AggregationFunction
{
   None,
   Sum,
   Avg
}

private AggregationFunction? selectedTotalAggregation;
public AggregationFunction? SelectedTotalAggregation
{
   get { return this.selectedTotalAggregation; }
   set { SetField(ref this.selectedTotalAggregation, value); }  // this calls OnPropertyNotify automatically
}

public IEnumerable<AggregationFunction?> TotalsAggregationFunctions
{
   get
   {
      // no matter what I return, nothing works when hide the column...
      return new AggregationFunction?[] { AggregationFunction.None, AggregationFunction.Sum, AggregationFunction.Avg, AggregationFunction.Min, AggregationFunction.Max };
   }
}
```